# C# InputSimulator: choosing key from combobox

Tags: c#, inputsimulator

I have array filled with key names from InputSimulator.

```
readonly string[] keys = new string[119] 
    {   
        "",
        "TAB",
        "RETURN",
        "SHIFT",
        "CONTROL", 
        ...
    }
```

After that I fill comboboxes with this strings.
There are 3 comboboxes.

So, I would like to use such a function:

```
sim.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_V);
```

Is it possible to fill arguments of this function with key names which were selected in comboboxes?

It was obivious for me, how to do it with SendKeys function, cause it was using string as an argument, but now I need to do it with InputSimulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the array contain all the keys in the order they are in on the `VirtualKeyCode` Enumeration. Then you just cast it into a `VirtualKeyCode` as soon as you use `ModifiedKeyStroke`.

like so

`sim.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke((VirtualKeyCode)combobox1.SelectedIndex, (VirtualKeyCode)combobox2.SelectedIndex);`

EDIT:

Beter yet, you could use `Enum.Parse(typeof(VirtualKeyCode), comboboxvalue)` to get the desired enum based on the combobox string value and use it in the function.

Like so:

```
sim.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke((VirtualKeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(VirtualKeyCode), combobox1value), (VirtualKeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(VirtualKeyCode), combobox2value);
```